# Why doesn't my new iPod Touch have a camera?

Tags: ipod-touch, camera

I got a new, 32gb iPod Touch for my birthday in August, and I really love it. It's faster than my old one and holds all my songs, but I thought it would have a camera. I don't know much about the Apple Store (I don't go there often), but I thought that after a new model comes out, they stop selling the old one. This one was bought in summer of 2011, so I was under the impression that it would be a 4th generation with a camera and all. Am I not accessing the camera? Is it there, but I can't see it? Is there an app I need to buy to use it?

Answer (score 6):

Apple sells refurbished models of many of their products, including the iPod Touch. So it's quite possible that you have a previous model (also known as the 3rd generation iPod touch).

To tell, if your iPod Touch looks like this:

[image]

you have the 3rd generation (without the camera).

If it looks like this:

[image]

you have the 4th generation model, with the camera.

If it doesn't look like either of these, you have an even earlier model, but that is unlikely as Apple rarely sells models two generations old. You can see the full range, and get more help on determining the model from this website. [Identifying iPod Models](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1353#iPod_Touch_4G)

Answer (score 1):

If it has a camera, there should be a Camera app already installed which you should be able to find on one of your screens.

If you can’t find the camera app in spotlight or in the App Store to reinstall it, and you’re sure you physically have a camera, restore the device in iTunes to wipe and reload all the software before you seek hardware service.